# What is wrong with the below code when i am trying to add the object to the List

Tags: java

Please refer below code and let me know where i am going wrong

```
public class EmployeeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new Employee("1026751","Jack Reacher"));
        list.add(new Employee("1026722","Tom Cruise"));

        System.out.println(list);
        //Employee a = list.get(0);
        Employee e = list.get(0);
        Employee p = list.get(1);
        list.clear();
        e.setEmployeeName("Rishabh Bansal");
        list.add(e);
        e.setEmployeeName("Jack Reacher");
        list.add(e);
        list.add(p);
        System.out.println(list);


    }

}
```

i want to add the element on the

```
 0 index as "1026751","Rishabh Bansal" 
 1 index as "1026751","Jack Reacher"
 2 index as "1026722","Tom Cruise"
```

but instead of it i am getting the list as -:

```
[Employee [employeeId=1026751, employeeName=Jack Reacher], Employee [employeeId=1026751, employeeName=Jack Reacher], Employee [employeeId=1026722, employeeName=Tom Cruise]]
```

Why the element on 0 index is getting changed ...

Comment: Because you change it here `e.setEmployeeName("Jack Reacher");` even though before you do `e.setEmployeeName("Rishabh Bansal");` you are dealing with the same object because you are using the same reference `e` every time.

Comment: `e` is the same Object that is being added twice, so if you change the Object, the change will be reflected twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You added the same reference to an `Employee` twice:

```
e.setEmployeeName("Rishabh Bansal");
list.add(e);
e.setEmployeeName("Jack Reacher");
list.add(e);
```

But these two references still refer to the *same* object, which you are changing.

So you should create new objects here, too.

Comment: What code do you mean? How to create `Employee` objects? You already have that in your code?!? I'm puzzled ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's what your list looks like after the first two add() :

```
[oid1, oid2]
```

oid1 and oid2 are "pointers" (references) to objects whose state is held elsewhere :

```
oid1 := Employee("1026751","Jack Reacher")
oid2 := Employee("1026722","Tom Cruise")
```

After the two .get() you have two "handles" on these objects :

```
e == oid1
p == oid2
```

Then you clear the list such that the list becomes :

[]

Then you change the state of one of your two objects and add that to the list such that you have :

```
[oid1]
oid1 := Employee("1026751","Rishabh Bansal")
oid2 := Employee("1026722","Tom Cruise")
```

Then you change the state of that same object and add it again to the list such that you have :

```
[oid1, oid1]
oid1 := Employee("1026751","Jack Reacher")
oid2 := Employee("1026722","Tom Cruise")
```

So the object on index 0 got changed simply because you asked for it.  If you have only one object, you have only one state.  Want three states on a list ?  Need three objects.